# How to fetched filtered data from array list?

Tags: android, list, filter, custom-lists

I have two `ArrayList` one list is custom `class` list and another one is `Integer` list. `Integer` list contains ids and I want to fetch data from custom class list whose id is available in `Integer` list. And both of list have 1000  of records.

So please tell me optimized way to do this

Comment: Post your custom class list here, on this we can have a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you rough idea about the approach you might want to consider, This example uses `ArrayList` to search the data in the list,

few things I have assumed like `CustomClass` as I don't know what it is.

Even though this code works you should consider something which has `HashMap` which will be much faster than this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FindTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /**
         * this initializes you integer list
         * */
        ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            integers.add(i);
        }

        /**
         * this initializes you MyCustomeData list
         * */
        ArrayList<MyCustomeData> customeDatas = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            customeDatas.add(new MyCustomeData(i));
        }


        /**
         * here you will collect the serach result list
         * */
        ArrayList<MyCustomeData> tempMyCustomeDatas = searchDate(integers, customeDatas);


    }

    /**
     * this is the important method as it looks for the relevant ids
     * */
    private static ArrayList<MyCustomeData> searchDate(ArrayList<Integer> integers, ArrayList<MyCustomeData> customeDatas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<MyCustomeData> list = new  ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < customeDatas.size(); j++) {
                if (integers.get(i)== customeDatas.get(i).getId()) {
                    list.add(customeDatas.get(i));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return list;
    }




}

 /**
  * I will assume that this is your custom Class who'es Id you want to find out
  * */
 class MyCustomeData{

    private int id;

    public MyCustomeData(int id){
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.id = id;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```